# How to add Google UK to IE 10 in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, google-search

you can add google as search provider in IE 10 under Windows 8. But I cant find a way to add google UK.

in previous versions you could search for TEST and then create a custom provider with the url... but I cant find it in IE 10.

anyone succeeded in this ?

Comment: You're supposed to go to tools, Manage Addons, Search Providers, 'Find more search providers', but all I could find was Google Canada, sorry. You wind up looking at the following URL: http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/PinnedSites

Comment: Having said that, take a look at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes - your providers are here. You can edit them. I have no idea where the GUIDs come from. I was able to successfully add my favorite StackExchange sites back but that was a long time ago, and I don't have a specific procedure written up for it. There's probably a 'correct' way to do it which isn't mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up you IE10 and visit this page, http://www.iegallery.com/en-gb/Addons/Details/3381, then click on **Add to Internet Explorer**.

In case you want to add Google search engine from another region, you can go back to http://www.iegallery.com/en-gb/AddOns, and click on the language at the top of the page, and then from the popup menue pick a different language, e.g. United States (English) Select Search and Google US should be appear in the search results.

Comment: amazing!! how come it is not possible to google the answer like that? :)

Comment: This still makes it google.com. I have English: UK & Ireland. I want it to use google.co.uk

Comment: He asks how to setup Google UK. You describe Google US, distinctly not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed with the registry key suggested by Mark Allen.

1)  Set google.com as your default search engine.
2)  Press Windows key + R to open the run dialog.
3)  Type regedit to open the registry editor.
4)  Maybe a good idea to go File and export the registry in case you make a mistake.
5)  Navigate to; HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes 
6)  Look in the folders there and find the URL value
7)  Change from google.com to google.co.uk
8)  Close regedit and restart IE – you should be done.